# How can i echo the name after a login

Tags: php, logging, authentication, dreamweaver

Im using dreamweaver and wamp phpmyadmin. I made a login system in a Lightbox. It works perfectly. 
The form i made it's so it requires the email and password of the user. 
I want the Name of the person loging in to show on the index page as a (example) "Welcome, Monica", instead of the email which is the required field as you log in.

I have 
 At the login validation it says (dreamweaver put it automatically

```
     $$loginusername=$ POST ('email')
     $PASSWORD=$ POST ('password')
```

With some other longin codding the down it says

```
     $loginusername=[$ SESSION (MM_Username)]
```

Then where i have the "Welcome " to show, i wrote, as i saw on a video to do,

```
     If (isset $ SESSION (MM_USERNAME))

     echo "Welcome, "
     echo ($ SESSION (MM_USERNAME))
```

I dont want to echo the username which is the email, i want to echo the name registered in the database.

I tried doing a Recorset (query) like this

```
     SELECT users.name
     FROM users
     Where email LIKE %colname%
```

When i hit Test in the recorsets panel, it makes me enter an email to see if its working, and it is, it shows the name NOT the email. But when i put it where i think it should go,(on the echo form)on the script it keeps on showing the email.... What do i have to do so it shows the Name of the user NOT the email!!! HELP???

Comment: You have answered your own question - you need to query your database to find the name that belongs with the login. I'm not sure what sets the session variable `MM_Username`, but as you found, it's the email address and not the name.

Comment: What are you using? MySQL? MySQLi? PDO?

Comment: Its the email address! thats what the user will use to login but what i want to reflect is a Welcome with the name,... im using MySQL!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're almost there. On the side of dreamweaver under the database tab you should be able to see your recordset. If you open it up you should also be able to see all the columns in the database created by that recordset (such as firstname). Just click and drag the firstname part of the recordset to where you want it and the code will generate automatically.